# Объект с максимальным числом свойств

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

Необходимо написать функцию, которая принимала бы неопределенное количество аргументов в виде объектов и возвращала бы объект с максимальным количеством свойств.

Comment: Что вам мешает написать эту функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getMaxPropObject = function() {
    var MaxPropObject = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    for(var k in arguments[i])
         MaxPropObject[k] = arguments[i][k]
    }
    return MaxPropObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, например:

```
function f() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        var index = 0;
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            var c = Object.keys(arguments[i]).length;
            if (c > count) {
                count = c;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return arguments[index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getMaxPropObject = function(fx_ArrObject) {
    var Count = 0;
    var MaxProp = 0;
    var MaxPropObject = {};

    fx_ArrObject.forEach(function(iObject){
        var Count = 0;
        for (Prop in iObject) 
            ++Count;
        if (Count > MaxProp) {
            MaxProp = Count;
            MaxPropObject = iObject;
        }
    });

    return MaxPropObject;
}
```

Comment: Тут в функцию передается массив, а в вопросе спрашивали про неопределенное число аргументов.